# GeoJeson geometry color fill shows defects when zooming or panning the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, kml

It is a Leaflet.JS 1.6.0 map with L.geoJSON converted from a KML file (using QGis) setting the layer color fill to each region:

```
// Sets the map
let latLon = [-22.228, -42.764];
const map = L.map('mapa').setView(latLon, 7.5);

// Loads de tile
L.tileLayer('https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=730kQ4LA2kCGmymETvmL', {
    attribution: '<a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/"target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a><a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
}).addTo(map);

// Sets the region variable to the features from the data file loaded in the head
const regiao = regioes.features;

// Fetches name and color from the geoJSON file
for (i = 0; i < regiao.length; i++) {
    const nome = regiao[i].properties.nome;
    const cor = regiao[i].properties.cor;
    // Sets color to the respective region
    L.geoJSON(regiao[i], {
        style: function (geoJsonFeature) {
            return {
                weight: 2,
                color: '#000',
                fill: true,
                fillColor: cor,
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            }
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

The problem occurs either when zooming in or panning until a part of the color filled area is outside the visualization limits. 
Parts of the colored area became transparent, the shape and size of the defect varies on how much of the boundaries is outside the visual limits of the map.: [image]

The code and the problem can be visited at https://ses-uerj.sd.eti.br/

Comment: Could you share a sample of GeoJSON data that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I've edited the GeoJSON file to incorporate the variable delaration const. It can be download here: https://ses-uerj.sd.eti.br/dados/regioes_saude_rj.js

Answer (score 1):

That's a symptom typical of applying a `fill` to a `L.Polyline` - internally, Leaflet clips *all* points of `L.Polyline`s which are outside of the viewable area of the map. The effect is clearer when setting the [renderer's `padding`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#renderer-padding) to zero. By contrast, Leaflet clips points of `L.Polygon`s too, but maintaining the basic topology of the closed area.

If you have a closer look at your data at https://ses-uerj.sd.eti.br/dados/regioes_saude_rj.js , you'll see things like...

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": { "nome": "Baixada Litoranea", "cor": "#f7fbff" },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [-42.23846, -22.60818],
      [-42.24684, -22.61272],
```

Your data is GeoJSON `LineString`s! Your features will get the `L.Polyline` treatment instead of the `L.Polygon` treatment. From a Leaflet standpoint, this is a [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in%2C_garbage_out) problem.

Do check the data in the KML file (is the original data polylines or polygons?), and the way that you're converting the data using Qgis. Something is wrong there, as there's a [sliver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliver_polygon) connecting Ilha do Governador to the mainland:

[image: sliver]

It would be possible to manually edit the GeoJSON data and replace the `LineString`s with `Polygon`s, but since there are other data artefacts (i.e. slivers), you should ensure your data (and your data conversion) is clean and consistent from the beginning.

Comment: Hi Ivan, I tryed manually replacing LineString by Polygon, but now I get Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.

Comment: Please don't try to edit GeoJSON manually if you haven't read [RFC 7946](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946) (sections 3.1 and appendix A), specifically don't change the geometry type if you don't know about how polygons have inner and outer rings.

Comment: Thank you again, IvanSanchez. It took some work finding overlapped and open nodes in QGis, but finally I managed to produce a full Polygon/MultiPolygon layer.